# What script does set my QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR env variable to zero by default?

Tags: qt

I'm struggling to set default value of `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` in my system (debian bullseye). But it seems that value I put a setter into `.profile` is ignored. Anyway the environment variale is set but its vaule is zero. I searched my `.profile`, `.xsessionrc`, and the whole `/etc` for it and didn't find anything. So my question is who sets the default value of `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` and how to alter this value for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with exactly the same question (debian sid) today and found the culprit. It is the application `startplasma-x11` itself.

You can check it yourself by downloading the source of `plasma-workspace`. In `startplasma.cpp` of version 5.27.2 starting at line 335 you will find:

```
    qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "0");

    qputenv("KDE_FULL_SESSION", "true");
    qputenv("KDE_SESSION_VERSION", "5");
    qputenv("KDE_SESSION_UID", QByteArray::number(getuid()));
    qputenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP", "KDE");

    qputenv("KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE", "1");
```

I think i will remove this line and compile it myself to be able to set this variable via `.profile` or ...

Nevertheless, this would not be the final solution as on upgrade it would need a recompile.

Comment: I resorted to setting it with env individually for some apps shortcuts; anyway - HiDpi support in linux sucks awfully